# Error while sending test mailing from CME in Web 8.1

Tags: web8, outbound-email

We upgrade tridion recently from 2013 sp1 to web 8.1 .While triggering test mailing we are getting following error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.OutboundEmail.Templating, Version=7.1.0.1296, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Looking at the error, it feels like Templating dll is from 2013 sp1 so might you are missing some upgrade steps.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the upgrade involves starting Template Builder and selecting `Create Default Building Blocks` from the `Tools` menu and then selecting the *parent* folder of your existing `Default Templates` folder.

That will update all of the default templates to the latest version, including Audience Manager / Outbound E-mail, Experience Optimization, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading  new Tridion.OutboundEmail.Templating.Templates.dll which is located inside %TRIDION%/bin into Outbound E-mail default  Tridion.OutboundEmail.Templating.Templates TBB resolve the problem.